# cakephp-upload won´t validate

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I´am using the plugin 
https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload
for image upload.
I won´t to disable adding post without uploaded image.
How to write validation to it?

```
class BlogContent extends AppModel
{

public $validate = array(
    'title' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'message' => 'Titulok musí byť zadaný'
    ),
    'text' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'required' => true,
        'message' => 'Text musí byť zadaný'
    ),
    'photo' => array(
        'isUpload' => array(
            'rule' => 'isFileUpload',
            'required' => true,
            'message' => 'Článok musí obsahovať obrázok',
             'last' => false
        ),
        'isCompletedUpload' => array(
            'rule' => 'isCompletedUpload',
            'message' => 'Obrázok nebol úspešne nahratý',
            'last' => false
        ),
        'tempDirExists' => array(
            'rule' => 'tempDirExists',
            'message' => 'Priečinok TEMP nie je dostupný',
            'last' => false
        ),
...
```

If I use  `required=> true` for isUpload, it will never validates. However if I not type it, it will validates without uploading image.

View code: admin_add.ctp

```
<div class="blogContents form">
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('BlogContent', array('type' => 'file'));
    echo $this->Form->input('title', array('label' => 'Titulok'));
    echo $this->Form->input('text', array('class' => 'ckeditor', 'label' => ''));
    echo $this->Form->input('image', array('label' => '', 'type' => 'file', 'accept' => 'image/*'));
    echo $this->Html->link(__('Vybrať obrázok'), '#', array('class' => 'btn btn-default', 'id' => 'upload'));
    echo _('<p>Zvolený obrázok:</p>');
    echo $this->Html->div('filelist', '<p>Žiaden obrázok nebol zvolený</p>');
    echo $this->Form->input('image_dir', array('type' => 'hidden'));
    echo $this->Form->input('active', array('label' => 'Publikované'));
    echo $this->Form->submit(__('Uložiť článok'), array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) ?>
</div>
```